# Show that w-complete Posets and continuous aplications between them form a category

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I'm really lost with this thing that looks innocent but just can't figure out... can you help me?

> Show that $\omega$-complete Posets and continuous functions between them form a category.

Thank you!

P.S. Definitions: A poset $(X;\le)$ is $\omega$-complete if every monotone sequence (or chain) of $X$ has a supremum. A function $f:X\to Y$ between $\omega$-complete posets is continuous if, each time that $s$ is the supremum of a chain $C=(c_{n})_{n\in\Bbb N}$ in $X$, $f(s)$ is the supremum of the image of $C$ under $f$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $\omega$-complete posets $P$ and $Q$ let $C(P,Q)$ be the set of continuous functions from $P$ to $Q$. In order to show that you have a category, you need to show three things:

- For each $\omega$-complete poset $P$, the identity map $\mathrm{id}_P:P\to P$ is continuous.
- The composition of continuous maps is continuous.
- Composition of continuous maps is an associative operation.

The third is trivial: composition of functions is always associative. The other two are just a matter of checking the continuity of $\mathrm{id}_P$ for an arbitrary $\omega$-complete poset $P$, and checking that if $f\in C(P,Q)$ and $g\in C(Q,R)$, where $P,Q$, and $R$ are $\omega$-complete posets, then $g\circ f\in C(P,R)$.